# Cant find sql server management studio 2008 component in feature selection

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, installation

I have the Microsoft server 2008 express setup. So i wanted to install sql server management studio for create database etc. 
But i can not find the sql server management studio in the installation time. it shows some other component .

So where i get it wrong here ? am i installing the wrong version?

[image: sql feature selection]

Answer (score 1):

You have to download SQL Server with tools or download SSMS separately.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have to load it down separately [www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8961)

Answer (score 0):

I finally able to fix it. people who have same problem as me. you probably download the wrong version of sql server . here is the download link which install SQL server 2008 without a problem :)
[SSMS](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593)